# NoMethodError J2ME Codename One

Tags: java-me, codenameone

I am currently getting the following error on second startup on a single device we are testing on.

java/lang/NoSuchMethodError: No such method R.(Ljava/lang/String;)V.

Now the problem is because we don't control the build (it is built in the cloud) we are unable to disable Obfuscation so I can't see the method name that isn't available.

I have read online that it can be a problem with interface methods not being marked as abstract but I have gone through the project and made all methods abstract, no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a build hint to the build server j2me.obfuscation=false to disable obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks although this appears to generate a build that the phone sees as invalid?

Comment: it's possible that without obfuscation the result is too big, I'd suggest you to try the jar/jad on the emulator, use the WTK